# How to backup Avira virus definitions?

Tags: backup, anti-virus

Where are the Avira antivirus virus definitions stored? Is it possible to take a backup? Because if it is possible I won't need to download again on next installation(in case of system format).

Actually my question is when I format my pc, avira downloads updates from the start i.e. the version of the setup onwards. I want it to download only those updates which are newer than those I have. Updates are lost when we uninstall/format the PC. That's why I wanna backup them.

Answer (score 2):

You should *always* download the latest antivirus definitions after a re-build, and keep the system continuously up-to-date for as long as you have Internet access thereafter.  Otherwise, you almost may as well not have antivirus protection at all.

That being said, I do not know where Avira stores a copy of the definitions that would be useful for backup purposes, but most antivirus vendors do allow manual download of update files from their website.  These should serve just as well as a locally-copied backup, although you will have to download them regularly if you want your backup to stay up-to-date.

A quick Google search turned up this:  http://www.avira.com/en/support-vdf-update-info

Regardless, I still strongly suggest that you allow your antivirus application to handle its own updating after a rebuild and thereafter.  Only use manual updates for when your system is air-gapped from the Internet, or if it has trouble with an automatic update.